# Group by time slots from Unix timestamp

Tags: android, sqlite, epoch

I have date/time  saved as Unix time stamp (13 digits). What I am trying to do is to group the rows by time period/range. For example, like below,

```
    total_order |  time_slot
    24             10 AM - 2 PM
    36             2 PM - 6PM
    30             6 PM- 10PM
    42             10PM - 2AM
    28             2AM - 6AM
    8              6AM - 10AM
```

I am really drawing a blank on how to approach with this? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: timestamp % 86400 is the time of day (in GMT timezone) in seconds since midnight ...

Comment: @henry how do I group by the range?

Comment: You can use an array with one element per bucket. Loop through the records, determine the bucket and increment the corresponding array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strftime()` to extract the hours from the timestamp.
To get the number of the four-hour range, divide by four. (The offset is needed because the ranges are not alignted to the start of the day.)

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
GROUP BY strftime('%H', timestamp, 'unixepoch', '+2 hours') / 4
```

Comment: Is there any way to account for timezone in the query itself?

Comment: So for GMT + 5.30, it will be 'unixepoch', '+5.30 hours') / 4 ?

Comment: No; the `+2` is for a slot beginning at 2 AM. You have to combine both offsets.

Comment: Thanks. So, if I am understanding it correctly, for a slot to start at 6AM and GMT+5.30 timezone, the offset should be '+11.30 hours'